# Make a changable variable in a HTML Header

Tags: javascript, html, html-heading

So Im really new to javascript and html, and was wondering how I could make a changeable number/variable after "Your Score:"

```
Your Score: </h1>
```

(Before `</h1>`)
Code :

```
<style> #yourScore {
background-color: lightblue; color: black; padding: 40px; text-align: center;
}
</style>
<h1 id="yourScore">Your Score: </h1>
```

Full Code : https://pastebin.com/TLtjjerL

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using vanilla javascript:

```js
const yourScore = document.getElementById("your-score");

function updateYourScore(score) {
  yourScore.textContent = score;
}

updateYourScore(9);
```

```html
<h1>Your Score: <span id="your-score"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way using vanilla javascript.

```js
score = prompt("What is the score?");

document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
```

```css
.h1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1> Your Score: <span id="score"></span></h1>
```

Or in my opinion, you can use the easier way below using jQuery.

```js
score = prompt("What is the score?");

$(".score").html(score);
```

```css
.h1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> Your Score: <span class="score"></span></h1>
```

The `prompt()` is just an example to get the score value from you. You don't actually need it in your code.